# Unable to destroy supportMapFragment on onDestroy

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

I am facing OOM issue as the supportMapFragment doesn't get destroyed.

Xml used:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Code snippet :

```
mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions();
mapOptions.useViewLifecycleInFragment(true);
mMapFragment.newInstance(mapOptions);
```

//ondestroy calling

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    //clear all the data
    mMap.clear();
    mMapFragment.onDestroyView();

}
```

Followed the same as mentioned in the docs given:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment

Comment: The thing is, `onDestroy()` may not be called  - there is no guarantee that it will be invoked.

Comment: On destroy of activity gets called checked the part..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you're not setting options here to your mMapFragment:

```
mMapFragment.newInstance(mapOptions);
```

You are creating one more SupportMapFragment with this option and it's lost, because you didn't assign it.
[Documentation says](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions) , that GoogleMapsOptions

> Defines configuration GoogleMapOptions for a GoogleMap. These options
>   can be used when adding a map to your application programmatically (as
>   opposed to via XML).

If you want to call OnDestroy - you should create the map programmatically, without XML, like:

```
GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions();
mapOptions.useViewLifecycleInFragment(true);
mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(mapOptions);
```